# Printf arguments in OCaml

Tags: printf, ocaml

In OCaml, I obtain an error I do not understand when passing arguments which should work to `Printf.printf`.  It is probably because I do not understand that function completely, but I cannot pin down what does not work.

First, I define a function (used for logging):

```
utop # let log verbosity level str =
  if level <= verbosity then (
    Printf.printf "\nLevel %i: " level;
    Printf.printf str);;
val log : int -> int -> (unit, out_channel, unit) format -> unit = <fun>
```

All seems well, but then I obtain this:

```
utop # log 0 0 "%i" 0;;
Error: This function has type
         int -> int -> (unit, out_channel, unit) format -> unit
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

although the following works:

```
utop # Printf.printf;;
- : ('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a = <fun>
utop # Printf.printf "%i" 0;;
0- : unit = ()
```

So, how can I define a function which does what `log` intends to do ?

**Edit:** Indeed, `log 0 0 "%i" 0;;` looks like too many arguments (4 instead of 3), but so does `Printf.printf "%i" 0;;` (2 instead of 1), and it works. With partial application, this gives this:

```
utop # Printf.printf "%i";;
- : int -> unit = <fun>

utop # log 0 0 "%i";;
Error: This expression has type (unit, unit) CamlinternalFormatBasics.precision
       but an expression was expected of type
         (unit, int -> 'a) CamlinternalFormatBasics.precision
       Type unit is not compatible with type int -> 'a
```

Comment: This looks like a syntax error.  You have _three_ arguments, but you're applying _four_.

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianBurszley, I added an "Edit".

Comment: Defining your own printf-like function in ocaml is possible but it's weird. I can't find a tutorial for doing so. I've done it before, but I don't really understand it either. Examples can be found in libraries here and there but they don't explain how it works and they tend to be more complicated than you want. You can try https://github.com/dbuenzli/logs/blob/master/src/logs.ml or some other ocaml logging library that provides a function called logf or similar-sounding. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `printf`-like functions are variadic, in the sense that they accept a variable number of arguments. It is not really specific to `printf` and the family, you can define your own variadic functions in OCaml, this is fully supported by the type system. The only magic of printf is that the compiler translates a string literal, e.g., `"foo %d` to a value of type `format`.

Now, let's look at the type of the `printf` function,

```
('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a
```

Notice that it returns `'a` which is a type variable. Since `'a` could be anything it could be also a function. The `('a, out_channel, unit) format` is the type of the format string that defines the type of function that is generated by this format string. It is important to understand though, that despite that `"foo %d"` looks like a string, in fact, it is a special built-in value of type `_ format`, which has a literal that looks like a string (though not all valid strings are valid literals for the `_ format` type.

Just to demonstrate that the first argument of `printf` is not a string, let's try the following,

```
# Printf.printf ("foo " ^ "%d");;
Line 1, characters 14-29:
1 | Printf.printf ("foo " ^ "%d");;
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         ('a, out_channel, unit) format
```

Now, when we know that printf is not a typical function, let's define a printf-like function ourselves. For that we need to use the `kprintf`-family of functions, e.g.,

```
# #show Printf.ksprintf;;
val ksprintf : (string -> 'd) -> ('a, unit, string, 'd) format4 -> 'a
```

This function takes the function which receives the resulting string which we can log, for example,

```
# let log fmt = Printf.ksprintf (fun s -> print_endline ("log> "^s)) fmt;; 
val log : ('a, unit, string, unit) format4 -> 'a = <fun>
# log "foo";;
log> foo
- : unit = ()
```

This resulting function looks more like `sprintf`, i.e., it will play nicely with pretty-printing function that work with string as their output devices (this is a different topic). You may find it more easier to define your logging functions, using either `Printf.kfprintf` or, much better, using `Format.kasprintf` or `Format.kfprintf`. The latter two functions have the following types,

```
val kasprintf : (string -> 'a) -> ('b, formatter, unit, 'a) format4 -> 'b
val kfprintf : (formatter -> 'a) -> formatter ->
  ('b, formatter, unit, 'a) format4 -> 'b
```

But the type of format works with the `formatter` type (which is an abstraction of the output device) that is the type that the pretty printers (conventionally named `pp`) are accepting. So the log function defined using the `Format` module will play better with the existing libraries.

So, using `Format.kasprintf` we can define your log function as,

```
# let log verbosity level =
  Format.kasprintf (fun msg -> 
      if level <= verbosity then 
        Format.printf "Level %d: %s@\n%!" level msg);;

val log : int -> int -> ('a, Format.formatter, unit, unit) format4 -> 'a = <fun>
```

And here is how it could be used,

```
# log 0 0 "Hello, %s, %d times" "world" 3;;
Level 0: Hello, world, 3 times
- : unit = ()
```